# How to scrape data generated by javascript using python

Tags: javascript, python

I want to scrape the Number of participants of the following news.
The url is http://news.sina.com.cn/c/2013-07-11/175827642839.shtml
And I want to get the Number 820.
It is generated by javascript.
How can I get that number using simple way?

Comment: Sending Json to a python server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could analize javascript code and do the same in python. 
Or you can use [Selenium](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html) in Python.

**edit:**

Here example from selenium page changed to do what you need.

It open browser (firefox), wait 5 second (to load page) and get text

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://news.sina.com.cn/c/2013-07-11/175827642839.shtml ") # Load page
time.sleep(5) # Let the page load
try:
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'f_red')]") # get element on page
    print element.text # get element text
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find f_red"
browser.close()
```

Comment: I added example in my answer. It use Firefox to get what you need.

Comment: Yesterday on page was 820. Today on page is 823. So today my example give 823 (`print element.text`). Or I'm looking in wrong place.

Comment: Yeah,the code is  excellent,but it will open the FireFox browser.If I have millions of web page to scrape,it will not be effective. Can you have some tips for that?

Comment: I heared that there is `webdriver.i_dont_remember_name` which don't open any browser` but it still needs `time.sleep` to wait for javascript. For scraping I use urllib + pyQuery but it work only with HTML - so I get javascript, analyze what it is doing step by step, I look for source of information. If I find some url (mostly in ajax) I can try to use it directly in python. This way script can work fast enought to get milions pages (you can use `threads` to get more pages at the same time).

Comment: But sometimes script works too fast and server know that it have to be script or bot. Servers don't like bots - bots don't click advertisements and servers don't earn money :)